# Plupload - event on drag and drop

Tags: jquery, file-upload, drag-and-drop, plupload

I'm using [PlUpload plugin](http://plupload.com) for multiple file uploade. This is very good plugin and I made many customization to it so far. Also it has some events, for example `UploadComplete`, `BeforeUpload` and so on. Now I need an event that raised on Drag And Drop. something like google drive's drag and drop feature. In google drive, when you start dragging the files, this image shows up:
[image]

I want to have control on drag and drop. Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is old, I explain the answer for other people (like me) who had the same question:
As you can see in the [documentation](https://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/Uploader#events), there is no event in plupload which raises on drag and drop.
But instead, there is an event in plain html, who does the same (and is probably used in google drive). [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_dragevent.asp) is a link that explains the usage of the drag event.
This drag event is divided into different event types. As you want to have an image which shows up when you drag an element over it, you need the ondragenter event to start showing the image and the ondragleave (and drop) event to stop showing the image. You could also make an animation instead of an image.

**Here is a short example code how to use the Drag event:**

CSS:

```
#DropTarget {
  width: 500px; 
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

PHP:

```
<div id="DropTarget" ondrop="Drop(event)" ondragenter="DragEnter(event)" ondragleave="DragLeave(event)">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function DragEnter(event) {
  event.target.style.border = "2px dotted green";
}

function Drop(event) {
  event.target.style.border = "1px solid black";
  //Here something else you want to happen when the element is dropped
}

function DragLeave(event) {
    event.target.style.border = "1px solid black";
}
```

This code changes the border of the Drop zone when an element is dragged over it.